# Force disabled server selection when using cookie based session persistence?

Tags: haproxy

Let's say I have an HTTP configuration block like so:

```
listen testing
  bind 1.2.3.4:80
  balance roundrobin
  use-server server1 if { urlp_val(force) eq 1 }
  use-server server2 if { urlp_val(force) eq 2 }
  force-persist if { urlp(offline) -m bool }
  cookie SRVID insert indirect nocache
  server server1 1.2.3.5:9000 cookie 1
  server server2 1.2.3.6:9000 cookie 2
```

Then, at some point, I disable `server2` via the socket interface so that all connections to it are now forced over to `server1`. But `server2` isn't really offline, it is just undergoing maintenance and it should be checked before being re-enabled. So requesting `http://1.2.3.4/?force=2&offline=true` should be proxied to `server2`. But that's not happening, it's being proxied to `server1`.

If I add `option persist` then persistence will stay and no one will be directed to `server1` since `server2` wasn't really unavailable.

How can I accomplish my goal of stopping automatically load balanced traffic from going to `server2` but force conditional traffic to it when it is disabled?

Comment: I believe `option redispatch` is what you're looking for in conjunction with `option persist`

Comment: @user3137702 that's only if the backend server is actually offline, not just disabled

Comment: Ah that's right, and I didn't notice your `force-persist` either.  I think you may want to get rid of that directive, and use `option httpchk` which can check a specific url, e.g. `/downForMaint` and have your "maintenance mode" server return a 4xx or 5xx on that URI if it is down.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. Disabling the server is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I wasn't reading carefully.  Have you tried alternate matching on the force-persist?  e.g. `force-persist if { urlp(offline) -m str true}`?  Maybe the boolean match isn't working as expected.

Comment: Nope. That results in the same response -- server1's content.